# zabbix Errors:can't find the zabbix_java_gateway.conf

Tags: java, zabbix

I added -enable- Java in zabbix compilation, but failed to find a Java configuration file.
like this

---

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/zabbix --enable-server --enable-proxy --enable-agent --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl  -enable-java
```

---

then I make,but I can't find the zabbix_java_gateway.conf.

---

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /usr/local/zabbix/etc/
zabbix_agentd.conf   
zabbix_agentd.conf.d  
zabbix_proxy.conf  
zabbix_proxy.conf.d  
zabbix_server.conf  
zabbix_server.conf.d
```

---

what up?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have only one dash, but the correct parameter is with two dashes - `-enable-java`.

Second, Zabbix Java gateway does not have such a conf file, it uses `settings.sh` instead. In your case, it is likely to be in `/usr/local/sbin/zabbix_java`.

Comment: No,I found the problem isn't it . And i found the new problem is my machine the java_home is different to the configure'java way @Richlv